# No visible @interface for 'LoadingOverlay' declares the selector 'showOverlay:'

Tags: swift

I have this swift class

```
@objc public class LoadingOverlay : NSObject{

            @objc var overlayView : UIView!
            @objc var activityIndicator : UIActivityIndicatorView!

            @objc class var shared: LoadingOverlay {
                struct Static {
                    static let instance: LoadingOverlay = LoadingOverlay()
                }
                return Static.instance
            }

            @objc override init(){
                self.overlayView = UIView()
                self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

                overlayView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:0, y:0), size: CGSize(width:80, height:80))
                overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7)
                overlayView.clipsToBounds = true
                overlayView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                overlayView.layer.zPosition = 1

                activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:0, y:0), size: CGSize(width:40, height:40))
                activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x:overlayView.bounds.width / 2, y:overlayView.bounds.height / 2)
                activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
                overlayView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            }

            @objc public func showOverlay(view: UIView) {
                overlayView.center = view.center
                view.addSubview(overlayView)
                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            }

            @objc public func hideOverlayView() {

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.overlayView.removeFromSuperview()
                })
            }
        }
```

and I am calling this class in an objective c method

```
LoadingOverlay *sharedManager = [LoadingOverlay shared];
        [sharedManager showOverlay:(self.view)];
```

and I am getting this error

```
No visible @interface for 'LoadingOverlay' declares the selector 'showOverlay:'
```

how can I solve it ?

Comment: Check the content of your bridging header "YourAppProductName-Swift.h", which must be included in you ObjC code. I guess the ObjC name for `showOverlay(view:)` would be `showOverlayWithView:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective c appends with(labelOfParameter) , so convert it to

```
 LoadingOverlay *sharedManager = [LoadingOverlay shared];
 [sharedManager showOverlayWithView:self.view];
```